# Soap problem with linked list - infopath

Tags: infopath, soap

When I tried to migrate a list with some list wchich are connected migration works great, but when I tried to connect another list with migrated list, and I tried use existing list it give me SOAP error on InfoPath, that saying that list don't existing:

[image]

But the List Exists The name of the list.

Meybe the grid is a problem.